# Visualforce Tab in Lightning UI creating invalid Partner Server URL

Tags: visualforce, lightning, soap-api

On a Visualforce page the merge field `{!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_420}` is used to get the Parther SOAP API endpoint.

This has been working fine for many years (allowing for changes to the API version).

However, it is now producing a server URL that doesn't conform to the validation requirements set out in [Secure Coding Single Sign On](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Single_Sign_On). The validation requires a domain of either ***.salesforce.com** or ***.force.com**.

In Spring '18 orgs where it still works:

- https://mydomain-dev-ed--mynamespace.visual.force.com/services/Soap/u/42.0/00D700000000001

In Spring '18 orgs where it no longer works:

- https://mydomain-dev-ed--mynamespace.visualforce.com/services/Soap/u/42.0/00D700000000001

Note how it is now returning a **visualforce.com** domain, which fails the existing validation that is required to secure external services.

What is causing the Partner API domain to vary between orgs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to track the cause down.

It is the [**Remove Instance Names From URLs for Visualforce, Community Builder, Site.com Studio, and Content Files**](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_vf_instance_names_removed.htm) critical update.

When activated the it changes the Partner URL format of Visualforce pages.

From the Critical Update impact details:

> This org has a My Domain name of **mydomain-dev-ed**. When we remove the instance name from your URLs, your new hostnames will change. Some examples of this are the following:
>
> - **mydomain-dev-ed--dfb.visualforce.com** will replace **mydomain-dev-ed--dfb.na64.visual.force.com**
> - mydomain-dev-ed--dfb.documentforce.com will replace mydomain-dev-ed--dfb.na64.content.force.com
> - mydomain-dev-ed.builder.salesforce-communities.com will replace mydomain-dev-ed--sitestudio.na64.force.com
> - mydomain-dev-ed.preview.salesforce-communities.com will replace mydomain-dev-ed--sitepreview.na64.force.com
> - mydomain-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com will replace mydomain-dev-ed--livepreview.na64.force.com
>
> Note that all *.na64.content.force.com URLs will be replaced with *.documentforce.com.
>
> After this update, any URL that includes the instance name, such as a bookmark, will automatically redirect to the new hostname.

I'll reach out to the security team about updating the regex that validates the server URL in the [Secure Coding Single Sign On](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Single_Sign_On) document.

Interim Regex to allow for visualforce.com domain:

```
 https:\/\/[^/?]+\.(sales|visual\.?)force\.com\/services\/(S|s)(O|o)(A|a)(P|p)\/(u|c|m)\/.*
```

I'm not sure Regex is the best way to validate this. E.g. a server URL from a community site may have an extra segment in the path before the `/services/Soap/u/` segments. However, that is probably something to be addressed in another question.

See also:

- Partner Alert: [Visualforce Domain Name Change](https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerAlert?id=a033A00000F4oUFQAZ)